# How to find out the length of an expression within a column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not a database administrator but I often have to query databases to do my job. Recently I've been tasked with querying for the length of a semi-colon separated expression within a database column. It will probably be easier to show as a made-up example table and column:

- Table is `Table1`.
- Column is `Column1`.

Values of two rows in `Table1.Column1` look like this:

```
principal_name='Joe Schmoe'; marital_status='m'; shoe_size='12.5';
message='This is a message which is 45 characters long'; 
years_active='15'

principal_name='Jim Schmim'; marital_status='s'; shoe_size='10.5'; 
message='This is a xxxxxxxxxxx message which is 57 characters long'; 
years_active='6'
```

I need to query `Table1.Column1` and find out out how many rows have more than 50 characters in the message portion of this column.

If this column only had a single value, I could just use something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE LEN(column1) > 40
```

However, I don't need to know how many total characters the field has, only how many are between `message=` and `;`

I have never dealt with a column that has multiple values separated by semicolons before, so I don't know how to query for what I need to know.

Comment: That's why using multivalued fields is a bad idea

Comment: indeed - refer to "but I often have to query databases to do my job. Recently I've been tasked..." :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there's always the same parts within column1, in the same order, something **like**
`where ( CharIndex('years_active=',column1) - CharIndex('message=',column1)  ) >50`
(give or take some adjustments for lengths of descriptions, etc)

Comment: p.s. These are not the actual tables/columns. I just made these up to avoid putting real company data. And in case anyone wants to know why I need this information, it's because there is a program that takes the message data and puts it into a new table in a new database, but sometimes this fails because the new table is only varchar(50).  My next job, after identifying the offending rows, will be to find a way to truncate the strings prior to the data being migrated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in a custom function

```
Declare @str varchar(max);
set @str = 'aaaabc=thisisatest;aaaaa'
select LEN(substring(@str,CHARINDEX('=',@str,0)+1, CHARINDEX(';',@str,0)-CHARINDEX('=',@str,0)-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;with cte as
(
    select 'principal_name=''Joe Schmoe''; marital_status=''m''; shoe_size=''12.5'';message=''This is a message which is 45 characters long'';years_active=''15''' as column1
    union
    select 'principal_name=''Jim Schmim''; marital_status=''s''; shoe_size=''10.5''; message=''This is a xxxxxxxxxxx message which is 57 characters long''; years_active=''6'''
), 
cte2 as 
(
    SELECT ltrim(rtrim(r.value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'))) as Item from (
    select CONVERT(XML, N'<root><r>' + REPLACE(column1,';','</r><r>') + '</r></root>') as XmlString
    from cte ) x
    CROSS APPLY x.XmlString.nodes('//root/r') AS RECORDS(r)
)
--SELECT *, LEN(item) - 10 from cte2 x where x.Item like 'message=%' and LEN(item) > 50
SELECT COUNT(*) cnt from cte2 x where x.Item like 'message=%' and LEN(item) > 50
```